# openNLP java - multi term Portuguese NER

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm using openNLP API at java for a project that I'm working on. The thing is that with my program i only process words alone with no correspondence.
The code:

```
String line = input.nextLine();


          InputStream inputStreamTokenizer = new FileInputStream("/home/bruno/openNLP/apache-opennlp-1.7.2-src/models/pt-token.bin"); 
          TokenizerModel tokenModel = new TokenizerModel(inputStreamTokenizer); 

          //Instantiating the TokenizerME class 
          TokenizerME tokenizer = new TokenizerME(tokenModel); 
          String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize(line);


          InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/bruno/openNLP/apache-opennlp-1.7.2-src/models/pt-sent.bin"); 
          SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(inputStream); 

          //Instantiating the SentenceDetectorME class 
          SentenceDetectorME detector = new SentenceDetectorME(model);  

          //Detecting the sentence
          String sentences[] = detector.sentDetect(line); 

          //Loading the NER-location model 
          //InputStream inputStreamLocFinder = new FileInputStream("/home/bruno/openNLP/apache-opennlp-1.7.2-src/models/en-ner-location.bin");       
          //TokenNameFinderModel model = new TokenNameFinderModel(inputStreamLocFinder);

          //Loading the NER-person model 
          InputStream inputStreamNameFinder = new FileInputStream("/home/bruno/TryOllie/data/pt-ner-floresta.bin");       
          TokenNameFinderModel model2 = new TokenNameFinderModel(inputStreamNameFinder);

          //Instantiating the NameFinderME class 
          NameFinderME nameFinder2 = new NameFinderME(model2);

          //Finding the names of a location 
          Span nameSpans2[] = nameFinder2.find(tokens);

          //Printing the spans of the locations in the sentence 
          //for(Span s: nameSpans)        
             //System.out.println(s.toString()+"  "+tokens[s.getStart()]);

          Set<String> x = new HashSet<String>();
          x.add("event");
          x.add("artprod");
          x.add("place");
          x.add("organization");
          x.add("person");
          x.add("numeric");

          SimpleTokenizer simpleTokenizer = SimpleTokenizer.INSTANCE;  
          Span[] tokenz = simpleTokenizer.tokenizePos(line);
          Set<String> tk = new HashSet<String>();
          for( Span tok : tokenz){
              tk.add(line.substring(tok.getStart(), tok.getEnd()));
          }

          for(Span n: nameSpans2)
          {
              if(x.contains(n.getType()))
                  System.out.println(n.toString()+ " -> " + tokens[n.getStart()]);

          }
```

The  output i get is:

```
Ficheiro com extensao: file.txt
[1..2) event -> choque[3..4) event -> cadeia[6..7) artprod -> viaturas[13..14) event -> feira[16..18) place -> Avenida[20..21) place -> Porto[24..25) event -> incêndio[2..3) event -> acidente[5..6) artprod -> viaturas[44..45) organization -> JN[46..47) person -> António[47..48) place -> Campos[54..60) organization -> Batalhão[1..2) event -> acidente[6..8) numeric -> 9[11..12) place -> Porto-Matosinhos[21..22) event -> ocorrência[29..30) artprod -> .[4..5) organization -> Sapadores[7..10) organization -> Bombeiros[14..15) numeric -> 15
```

What im trying to do is a multi term NER, like Antonio Campos is a person, not Person -> Antonio and Place -> Campos, or Organisation -> Universidade Nova de Lisboa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are printing the wrong data structure. The span getSart and getEnd will point to the sequence of tokens that are part of the entity. You are printing just the first token.

Also, you are doing tokenization before sentence detection.

Try the following code:

```
// load the models outside your loop
InputStream inputStream =
    new FileInputStream("/home/bruno/openNLP/apache-opennlp-1.7.2-src/models/pt-sent.bin");
SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(inputStream);

//Instantiating the SentenceDetectorME class 
SentenceDetectorME detector = new SentenceDetectorME(model);

InputStream inputStreamTokenizer =
    new FileInputStream("/home/bruno/openNLP/apache-opennlp-1.7.2-src/models/pt-token.bin");
TokenizerModel tokenModel = new TokenizerModel(inputStreamTokenizer);
//Instantiating the TokenizerME class 
TokenizerME tokenizer = new TokenizerME(tokenModel);


//Loading the NER-person model 
InputStream inputStreamNameFinder = new FileInputStream("/home/bruno/TryOllie/data/pt-ner-floresta.bin");
TokenNameFinderModel model2 = new TokenNameFinderModel(inputStreamNameFinder);

//Instantiating the NameFinderME class 
NameFinderME nameFinder2 = new NameFinderME(model2);

String line = input.nextLine();

while(line != null) {

  // first we find sentences
  String sentences[] = detector.sentDetect(line);

  for (String sentence :
      sentences) {
    // now we find the sentence tokens
    String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence);

    // now we are good to apply NER
    Span[] nameSpans = nameFinder2.find(tokens);

    // now we can print the spans
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Span.spansToStrings(nameSpans, tokens)));

    line = input.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer wcolen, i've tryed  that solutions, but the output was: 
Ficheiro com extensao: file.txt
[Ljava.lang.String;@6f2b958e
[Ljava.lang.String;@1eb44e46
[Ljava.lang.String;@6504e3b2
[Ljava.lang.String;@515f550a
[Ljava.lang.String;@626b2d4a
[Ljava.lang.String;@5e91993f
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at ner.Wiki.main(Wiki.java:76)
</code>

I've tryed other methods output  like tostring for..and it was the same as before,am i doing something wrong here? thank you

Comment: `Span.spansToStrings(...) ` returns an array of strings. Try again using `Arrays.toString(Span.spansToStrings(nameSpans, tokens))`

Answer (score 0):

**Stanford-NLP** process only on single word. Even if you give coreNLP a  Sentence , it break into token and process on them one by one. and I never heard NER apply on multi term.

Comment: Im breaking the text into sentences, and tokenize each word, so my program only look at each word separately, and that where's my problem lies, i have to tokenize, but i need to look at words and find for example person Antonio Campos as one find, not Antonio as one person and Campos as a place, or another person... 
The same applies to organizations, like Univerity of Fernando Pessoa, i want to find it as one organization, not University as organization, Fernando as Person and Pessoa as other person

Comment: Alright , I understand your problem but this how **Stanford-NLP** work. NER only work after this process is done (tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma). So it is clear NER process only snigle word. may be this [link](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/dependencies.html) give you idea.

Comment: So, i only can look at single words, that means i cant solve my problem with that NER?